# How to deploy public static asset from magento 2 extension without adding it to the layout?

Tags: magento, magento2

I do have a static .js file added in view/frontend/web/script.js that I need to access publicly on request, without adding it to the html.

If I add it do default.xml or default_head_blocks.xml like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="extension_name::script.js"/>
  </head>
```

Then I can get it's URL (from html) and access it publicly. But I do not want the script to be available and load on every page.

How can I add it through extension, and get it's public URL, without adding it to the head blocks?

Answer (score -1):

You can add your static file in the public folder `pub/media/files/js/yourFile.js` with a fileUploader or push it yourself manually.

Comment: the question is about deploying the asset, not uploading it.